How to chage color of all tag at once using css
I want to change color of all a tags with the help of banner class. Can I do that in CSS?
<div class="banner">
  <a href="">MxForm</a>
  <a href="">antiX Forum</a>
  <a href="">contributes</a>
</div>

.banner {
  background-color: #114653;
  color: white;
}


.banner should work, assuming the a elements don't already have styling to override that. If so, try .banner > a

To change color of all a elements, you can try like this:
.banner {
    background-color: #114653;
    color: white;

    a {
        color: red;
    }
}


.banner > a { color: red; }

Shortest possible code is:
.banner  a { color: red; }
